# Cannot open UART on the 40-pin header

Tags: python, linux, google-coral

I am working on a Coral dev-board. I am trying to use UART1_TXD/RXD, UART3_TXD/RXD on the 40-pin header on the dev-board. I am following the tutorial [Connect to the GPIO pins](https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/dev-board/gpio/).

```
[serial_test.py]

from periphery import Serial

serial = Serial("/dev/ttyS0", 115200)

serial.write(b"Hello World!")

buf = serial.read(128, 0.5)
print("read %d bytes: _%s_" % (len(buf), buf))
serial.close()
```

When I test the board:

```
$ python3 serial_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/periphery/serial.py", line 166, in _open
    termios.tcsetattr(self._fd, termios.TCSANOW, [iflag, oflag, cflag, lflag, ispeed, ospeed, cc])
termios.error: (5, 'Input/output error')
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serial.py", line 5, in <module>
    serial = Serial("/dev/ttyS0", 115200)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/periphery/serial.py", line 60, in __init__
    self._open(devpath, baudrate, databits, parity, stopbits, xonxoff, rtscts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/periphery/serial.py", line 168, in _open
    raise SerialError(e.errno, "Setting serial port attributes: " + e.strerror)
AttributeError: 'error' object has no attribute 'errno'

$ stty -F /dev/ttyS0
stty: /dev/ttyS0: Input/output error
```

And the rest of the ttyS1~3 have the same result.

What is the correct device path?

Comment: You can usually find the device name in `dmesg`. I don't know an easy/programmatic way to lookup names to determine file system device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two UART ports exposed on the Coral dev board (UART1 and UART3) map to the following file handles:

- **UART1** → `/dev/ttymxc0`
- **UART3** → `/dev/ttymxc2`

You can access these ports through the [40-pin I/O connector](https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/dev-board/gpio/#gpio-header-pinout) and through the [serial console](https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/dev-board/datasheet/#serial-console-port) interface (the USB to UART bridge exposes two ports when connected to your workstation).

The current release of Mendel (chef) comes with the following caveats:

1. **UART1** is shared with the serial debug console. You will need to disable the console in Linux to use this port with applications.
2. **UART3** is not enabled by default in the base package. You need to update the packages on your board to enable this. We've added instructions to the [I/O documentation](https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/dev-board/gpio/).